# How to return value from a cell on an Excel spreadsheet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, spreadsheet

I've been trying to figure out a way to access an Excel Spreadsheet in JavaScript and return the values stored within the cells based on the row/column they're located in. So far, I've tried this function:

```
function ReadData(cell, row) {
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("Sudoku Puzzle.xls");
    var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
    var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell, row).Value;
    return data
}
```

But I get an Uncaught TypeError that states that ActiveXObject is not Defined. I know that the ActiveXObject isn't compatible in modern browsers, which was why I was wondering if there was an overall different method I could use.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Create a web page? Parse the excel file? Your best bet is to allow the user to upload the file to your website, using some backend server like flask, Django, php, node.js express, or many others. You then parse it there and return the relevant cells. Or maybe, maybe, [Web Assembly](https://blog.codeisc.com/2018/08/28/xlnt-wasm-intro.html). If it's only parsing you're after, try using python libraries or if you must use js, node js libraries.

Comment: I'm trying to do parsing - I'll definitely check out the Node.js libraries, thanks!

Comment: I guess you could make this work by using Edge in [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list), which supports ActiveX.  Yet, IE mode is really only intended to support enterprise legacy apps, not new designs.